# Figuring out relatively high page view logs among customer groups

Tags: python, sql, data-analysis

I am looking at GA app log data.
I have customer group A, B, C.

Say the data looks like this

```
group    id       page_name
A        1        Home
A        2        Home
A        2        Product C Page
A        2        Product A Page
A        3        Product A Page
A        3        Product C Page
A        4        Event Page
A        4        Product C Page
A        5        My Cart
A        5        Product C Page
B        6        Home
B        7        Home
B        8        My Cart
B        8        Product A Page
B        8        Event Page
B        9        My Cart
B        9        Product A Page
C        10       Home
C        11       My Cart
C        11       Product C Page
C        12       Product A Page
C        12       Event Page
...
```

I would like to figure out which pages do the customers in group A visits more frequently, in reltive sense, than customers in group B or C
where it should exclude pages that most of the customers in A, B, C visits often, and in a sense that it is significant - the views and number of people who visited that page should be of some size.

So for the above data, customers in group A visits Product C Page more frequently than group B/C. (Even though one customner visited roduct C Page, it is small compared to group A)

What would be a good way to measure this? Score it for each page_name?

It would be very nice to have TF-IDF sort of measurement.

Any idea would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!